# Custom REST API POST Endpoint Not Working, 404 Error

Tags: plugins, rest-api

I'm writing a plugin, and I'm having some trouble with the custom endpoint that takes in data from the front-end of the app (Angular), and will pass it another function to filter some data. I have the GET request to the product database working just fine, but the POST just returns a 404 error. Solutions I've tried include making sure that pretty permalinks were set, switching themes, all to no avail. I have also checked the wp-json file, and it is showing up in there. The code for this endpoint:

```
function get_awesome_params(WP_REST_Request $request) {
  // question attributes from angular code
  $parameters = $request->get_params();
  return new WP_REST_Response($parameters, 200);
}

add_action('rest_api_init', function() {
  register_rest_route('awesome/v1', '/awesomeparams', array(
    'methods' => WP_REST_Server::CREATABLE,
    'callback' => 'get_awesome_params',
    'permission_callback' => function () {
      return true;
    }
  ));
});
```

EDIT: Error message on visiting page is:

```
{
  code: "rest_no_route",
  message: "No route was found matching the URL and request method",
  data: {
    status: 404
  }
}
```

EDIT: Is it because I don't have a [custom content type](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-rest-api-support-for-custom-content-types/) set up for the $request argument?

Comment: Can you see your endpoint in http://{your_site}/wp-json/awesome/v1/ ?

Comment: Yeah, it's definitely appearing there.

Comment: How are you making the request to check? Are you definitely sending a POST request? Note that you’re not going to be able to access the endpoint in the browser.

Comment: Good to know, checking in Insomnia returns an empty array. I've checked the POST request from Angular using Firebase as a test env I'm a little more familiar with, and it's definitely sending what I expect it to.